Bad audio via Bluetooth after upgrading to Kubuntu 24.04
I have Pioneer SE-C4BT headphones that were working perfectly via Bluetooth in Kubuntu 22.04. After upgrading (actually could not reboot, so did a fresh install [no files lost]) to Kubuntu 24.04, as always, it took a while until I managed to get a Bluetooth connection with the Pioneer headphones (it was my fault perhaps?).
Now I can connect easily, but the sound is really bad, as if there is a faulty contact(!). It sounds tinny as if the sound is coming from inside a thin metal can. I have tried to remove pipewire to see if I could use whatever was in the previous version of Kubuntu, but in the process I broke my system (solved). There is also a microphone in the headphones. I need help getting normal sound quality via the Bluetooth connection.

I have included the fact the phones also have a mic. The version was already mentioned in the title, in the keywords and else where but I corrected where it was not clear. Thanks a lot. all the best.

Sorry I can not find anywhere in the question it says it has a mic. I did not nor will anyone else go looking what the features are of the type of headphones you have.

Of course, thank you David.

Your headphones are probably in headset mode. Headset mode uses ancient codecs that sound really bad. You need to switch your headphones to playback mode, where the microphone is inactive. Then, they will use less bad codecs (still bad by today's standards).
Go to System Settings -> Audio -> select your Headphones and in Profile select any of the "High Fidelity" options.


I don't know whether this is a Bluetoth standard or Ubuntu problem, but its ridiculous that any headphone sold in the last 15 years would even be able to produce such atrocious microphone sound.
